# Can a clay brick waste in a soil be a source of minerals for plants?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Clay brick is made by heating them so their clay structure changes. What i understand is ultimately all materials have one or another base minerals in it particularly here this brick still it remains in some other form. So after process of heat, those minerals or nutrients can remain in such condition a plant can absorb? Can a brick dust be a good source of nutrients for plants to grow?

Answer (score 2):

In general clay is not a good *source* of nutrients. [Clay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay) is a [class of hydrated alumina-silicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicate_minerals#Phyllosilicates) containing small amounts of metals. The alumina and silica are not plant [nutrients](http://www.ncagr.gov/cyber/kidswrld/plant/nutrient.htm), but some of the metals can be, in particular: potassium, magnesium, calcium, and iron.

Of these, only potassium is needed in large amounts by plants, and conversely, is fairly uncommon in clays. Calcium and iron are much more common, but are needed by plants in very small quantities.

For any mineral nutrient in any case I can think of, other sources would be better than clay.

Therefore, in the specific case where there was a mineral deficiency in the soil, and you didn't have another option available, clay *could* provide that nutrient.

However, clay can help plants in another manner. This [article](http://www.ncagr.gov/agronomi/pdffiles/sfn13.pdf) describes the ability of clay soil to attract and hold positive ions (metals that can be absorbed by plants are positive ions) due to the high surface area and negative surface charge of the clay particles. Since leaching can be a problem in nutrient-poor soils, having a soil component that "holds on" to those nutrients can be helpful.

Whether or not brick dust would be helpful to plant growth would depend on the specific case, in particular:

- The type of plant(s)
- The composition of the rest of the soil
- The type of clay used to make the brick
- The climate conditions (amount of rainfall, etc.)